# TypeScript Compiler API: best way to do multiple file transform?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Say we have several .ts files with multiple classes. We want to take part of every file's AST, transform them, merge them into a new AST, and then write it to a new .ts file. Is there any graceful way to do that?

**Updated 2020-03-08:**

Or in another word, is it possible to open two .ts files and merge the two ASTs and outputs to two new .ts files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution with [ts-clone-node](https://github.com/wessberg/ts-clone-node)

We can just create multiple transformers and multiple programs to cooperate